# what is the best practice for implementing only one user (Admin) in mvc 4 web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, membership

I want my website to be seen by anonymous users. and i don't want it to have a login /register user part.
i just need one user as administrator and its username and password is chosen manually.
what is the best practice to implement this login part (website has only one user for ever). 
my question is how to implement this one user login part, where store username and password and does it need a table in database?

Comment: `web.config` seems to be the best option for you. There's an explanation on [how to use `web.config`](http://forums.asp.net/t/1141844.aspx?Asterisk+for+All+users+or+Authenticated+Users+web+config+)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me - if you're having such a simple system, then merely storing the username / pwd in the web.config is fine.

I'd create a helper class to wrap up talking to the config file ([ConfigurationManager.AppSettings on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) and use and evaluate a simple "logon" action.

No table needed.

Finally - make sure you add the [AuthoriseAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) to your controller that will be doing the admin actions...

HTH

Comment: Seriously...in the `web.config`

Comment: Hey, keep it simple and all that... serious question:  what would you suggest otherwise? (genuinely interested!)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way - just delete the controller and the view responsible for registering new users, change the routing to the  login page and you're set.